# How would you run a SUR with nonlinear constraints?

Tags: constraint, seemingly-unrelated-regressions, restrictions

Chiappari et al (2012) estimate two Seemingly Unrelated Regressions like this:

$$
y_1 = a_1 + b_{11}x_1 + b_{12}x_2
$$

$$
y_2 = a_2 + b_{21}x_1 + b_{22}x_2
$$

Next, they want to test the hypothesis that $b_{11}/b_{12} = b_{21}/b_{22}$. So they estimate a model with that constraint, and then perform a LR test.

They don't go into much detail. How best would I estimate the restricted model? (Ideal answer would be R code or a package.) I guess I could just write down the likelihood function and maximize it using `mle()` or similar... is there an easier way? It's a nonlinear constraint, so I don't think `systemfit()` will work.

Comment: Hi: you probably need to construct the likelihood directly  ( which I guess is Gaussian ) and then use an optimizer such as Rvmminb which allows for constraints. John Nash wrote a text about optimization in R or you can check out the optimization task view on cran to get information on what is available in R as far as optimization.

Comment: @mlofton thanks. I guess I can do this. Do you know any good resources on how to estimate the standard errors when writing your own likelihood function? I'm ignorant about this.

Comment: hi: do you have access to this text: https://www.amazon.com/Econometric-Analysis-Time-Economics-Handbooks/dp/026208189X/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=andrew+harvey+economic+time+series&qid=1616937762&sr=8-5  A lot of this material  is explained quite nicely in there and I couldn't do it justice anyway ?